# Is there a good book on Circulant Matrices?

Tags: matrices, book-recommendation

I've done a bit of searching on Amazon and found the 1979 book by Philip J. Davis, but the typeset looks very old (blocked system print style) and I don't really like that. Does anyone know if there is a modern print version or a good alternative? Amazon doesn't really show much more else.

NB very loosely speaking *circulant matrices* are constructed from a single column vector, where each column of the matrix is a permutation of the previous column vector.

Comment: I think Strang's book Linear Algebra and its Applications has a good discussion of circulant matrices.

Comment: Davis's book *is* a good book and is the standard reference on circulant matrices.

Comment: Yes, that's what I gathered. My eyes just don't like the block print for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found an article by [Ikra et al, 2012](http://www.ams.org/notices/201203/rtx120300368p.pdf).